# EXEC:EXEC(0,0): Error : not found: python2

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to Merge my local branch to Target branch on server VSTS but it always failed by saying below error message:-

EXEC:EXEC(0,0): Error : not found: python2

My local publish works well but only issue when merging any source to target branch on VSTS.

[image]

Comment: Did you set automatic build branch policy for the Target branch? The error message you provided is build log, what error did you get when you perform merge? Have you build your project with VSTS before? How did you define your build definition?

Comment: Is python2 installed on your build agent? Is it part of the `PATH` environment variable?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by adding following command :-
Only issue was that Python was not installed on server, so these 2 command will help you to install that package:-

1) npm install nan
2) npm install node-sass

it works like a charm, thanks everyone for your reply.

Comment: Thanks @parveen. I just resolve the same issue with your instructions. thanks buddy :)